# Is it possible to make a contentEditable table cell for date?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table that has a cell that is `contentEditable`. My problem is that the content is a date, and is it possible that the cell will look like `<input type="date">`? So I can only update date if the column has a value and insert if it doesn't.

Here is what I got:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td><div contenteditable>" . $record['clientID'] . "</div></td>";
    echo "<td><div contenteditable>" . $record['date'] . "</div></td>";
    echo "<th><a href='test.php'>Update</a> ";
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Never ever trust user data. Yes, with Javascript you can try to force visitors to input a date only, but what will you do if a user disables Javascript? What will you do if a user uses a browser addon like Temper Data to edit the POST data any way they like?

Comment: There is errors in your html, missing the attribute `class=` before the `contenteditable` words, and the `"` around these words.

Comment: @AlFonce His html is perfectly fine. Contenteditable is not a value. It's a valid HTML5 attribute that has nothing to do with `class`. The attribute is a boolean that can be true or false. Because of this it's not nessesary to add a value to this attribute.

Comment: @icecub OK, I've learn something today :-)

Comment: Now seems like a good opportunity to extol the virtues of PHP's  mysql_ API. So, I shall begin:

Comment: @icecub
Thanks guys. Already Solve my problem. Now my problem is how do I update the row using my code.. Thanks again and see you. :)

Comment: @AlFonce Thanks. solved it

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks you.. Already solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I didn't use `contentEditable` instead I used `<input type="date">`.
The cell is editable as a date.

Here is what I did:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
   echo"<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $record['clientID'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td> <input type='date' value='". $record['date'] ."'> </td>";
   echo "<th><a href='test.php'>Update</a> ";
   echo"</tr>";
```

}

Comment: @StoychoTrenchev I solved it but I really want to try your solution. It looks helpful in updating the row. I just don't get what do you mean in "Get $queryResultArray and populate a form". I'm not really good at PHP and HTML. And thanks..
If you want, can you help me with my next problem? Its about updating the row.. :)))

Comment: Look at my code above. input type="date" is there. Whatever.

Comment: @StoychoTrenchev I made some fixes from your answer and it didn't work as I wanted but I got an idea from it to solve my other problem.thank you so much. You're a blessing!! Thank you!..

Answer (score 0):

Get $queryResultArray and populate a form:

```
$queryResultArray = [];

if ($myData) {
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
        $queryResultArray[] = $record;
    }
}


<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <?php foreach($queryResultArray as $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            all other data
            <td><input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $value['date'];?>"</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="<?php echo $value['clientID'];?>" value="Update"></td>   
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

After the form submit you get the edited row by name = cliendID and you edit the DB for this ID.

Comment: I solved my problem but since I am still figuring out how to update the row, I tried your code for it looks like it is helpful but done some editing for I put it inside PHP
`<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <?php foreach($queryResultArray as $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            all other data
            <td><input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $value['date'];?>"</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="<?php echo $value['clientID'];?>" value="Update"></td>   
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>`

Comment: can you please help me what do you mean in "get `$queryResultArray` and populate a form"
I'm still learning. Started making web just more than a week ago. Thanks